# Message passing with state[:pid] fails, freshly generated pid works

Tags: elixir, ex-unit

My second test is failing.

```
 1) test it jumps when it can (RunnerTest)
     test/runner_test.exs:15
     No message matching %{y: 1} after 100ms.
     The process mailbox is empty.
     stacktrace:
       test/runner_test.exs:18: (test)

defmodule RunnerTest do
  use ExUnit.Case
  doctest Runner

  setup_all do
    {:ok, pid: spawn(fn -> Runner.input() end)}
  end

  test "it increases its x position", state do
    avatar = %{x: 0, y: 0}
    send state[:pid], {:run, self, avatar}
    assert_receive %{x: 1}
  end

  test "it jumps when it can", state do
    avatar = %{x: 0, y: 0}
    send state[:pid], {:jump, self, avatar}
    assert_receive %{y: 1}
  end

end
```

Runner Module:

```
defmodule Runner do
    def input do
      receive do
       {:run, sender, mover} -> send sender, run(mover)
       {:jump, sender, mover} -> send sender, jump(mover)
     end
    end

    defp run(mover) do
        Map.merge(mover, %{x: mover.x + 1})
    end

    defp jump(mover) do
        case {mover.y} do
          {0} ->
            Map.merge(mover, %{y: mover.y + 1})
          _ ->
            mover
        end
    end

end
```

This test passes:

```
 test "it jumps when it can", state do
    avatar = %{x: 0, y: 0}
    pid = spawn(fn -> Runner.input() end)
    send pid, {:jump, self, avatar}
    assert_receive %{y: 1}
  end
```

Why is 1 test (run) working with setup but not the other (jump)?

Comment: You're not calling `input` again after the `receive`, so your process is probably dying after responding to 1 message.

Comment: Thanks Dogbert! I mistook setup_all to run every time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is 1 test (run) working with setup but not the other (jump)?

This is because your process only responds to one message and then dies and you're using `setup_all` instead of `setup`, which means the process is started only once, before the first test is ran, and the same `pid` is passed to all tests.

You can either change `setup_all` to `setup` if you want to spawn a fresh process for each test, or make your process respond to more than 1 message (possibly infinite using self recursion).